# Get URI for a stored file in StorageFile (WinRT)

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, isolatedstoragefile

I'm building a metro app, and I'm trying to get a Uri of an Image after saving it in the StorageFile, this is my code:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("samplefile.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

IRandomAccessStream raStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
IOutputStream outStream = raStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(outStream);
dw.WriteBytes(img); // I'm saving array of bytes
await outStream.FlushAsync();
```

I read this article:

and it says I can access the stored files using ms-appdata, so i tried this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///samplefile.dat", UriKind.Absolute);
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming it is stored in the Local folder, the URI should be

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/samplefile.dat");
```

Note the additional "local" in the middle.